# know the object selected from Listbox

Tags: gwt, listbox

I want to know the object that was selected in the ListBox in Gwt.
The "bookNames" is a Map.
I want to know which cell in the ListBox was chosen by user and use it.

```
        ListBox books = new ListBox();  
        final ListBox chapters = new ListBox();

        for(i=0;i<bookNamesString.length;i++)       // put books map into listbox (Map Starts from 1)
            books.addItem(bookNames.get(i+1));



            books.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    int i;


                    for(i=0;i<bookChapters.length;i++)
                    {
                        chapters.addItem("Chapter" + (i+1));
                    }

                }



            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
String selectedChapter = bookNames.get(chapters.getSelectedIndex() - 1);
```

Comment: Hey, I have a problem that the "chapters.getSelectedIndex()" returns -1 because the clickHandler works when touching the ListBox....
Is there another handler that works only when choosing an option from the ListBox ?? Thanks

Comment: You should use SelectionHandler.

Comment: could it be that SelectionHandler isn't defined for ListBox ? 
Because it's not working for me...

Comment: My bad - it's called "ChangeHandler". Your IDE should give you a list of all available options for every object.